# How can I add Bar code 39 to my RDL report

Tags: barcode, rdl

I am trying to add barcode 39 to my item number using Microsoft Report Builder. I am not sure about the code to get it work

Answer (score 0):

Code 3 of 9 (or code 39) is not an interleaved barcode, so you can actually just [download a font](https://www.dafont.com/3of9-barcode.font) which displays data as barcode elements. This works because code 39 is made of individual elements.

The code is very dense, and generally is harder to print if the content is long, compared to typically code 128.

Depending on your needs and budget, you can also purchase a commercial barcode module, or use a free module like [project zint](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zint/). This will give you more options such as line shaving, but obviously need to be spoken to using an API. For easiest approach: use a font.